# ActionBar not scaling onto ActionBar height

Tags: android, background-image, android-actionbar

I have a problem I don't understand:

I have just setup an ActionBar on my application (target SDK 11, theme Holo.Light). But when I set a background, either in XML or with setBackgroundDrawable(d) way, 
the background does not scale to the ActionBar height:

-If the drawable is too small, it is stretched to fill the action bar height.
-But if it is too high, it is not shrinked back and will overlay on the rest of the layout.

I have just followed the guidelines provided in the android dev, and also tried to set it via a DrawableBitmap, but with same results.

Thank you very much for any answer.

```
<resources>
<!-- the theme applied to the application or activity -->
<style name="CustomActivityTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    <!-- other activity and action bar styles here -->
</style>

<!-- style for the action bar backgrounds -->
<style name="MyActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/ab_background</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

To repeat what I understand you to be saying:

- If the image is 'small' then it is stretched to fill the ActionBar - this is the required behaviour, right?
- If the image is 'larger than small' then it overlaps the ActionBar region - this is NOT the required behviour, right?

What is the Drawable that you're setting as the background? Is it a 9-patch? Have you set the stretchable region correctly?

Comment: Hi thank you for your answer.
Yes you have well understood my point.

My drawable is a png file, taken from res/drawables. 
I have tried to to exactly the same thing on another device with another image bigger than the Action Bar and it scaled the right way so I'm a bit lost.

Comment: OK. Has the png been saved as a 9-patch (i.e. has it got the .9.png extension on it)? Also, is it actually a 9-patch file? That is, have you opened the file with <android_sdk_location>/tools/draw9patch and then edited the file according to http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/draw9patch.html and http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html#nine-patch ?